# Frame around inline images

Tags: python, image, docx

Is there a way to put frames around inline images with `python docx`?

I have something like:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Mm

document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
pic_cells = table.rows[0].cells
paragraph = pic_cells[0].paragraphs[0]
run = paragraph.add_run()
run.add_picture('testQR.png', width=Mm(15), height=Mm(15))
document.save('demo.docx')
```

I need to put a frame around the image to mark the border of this image (that should be identical with the image size).

How can I format this with the python `docx package`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `docx` currently has no support for such a feature.
Since you are using tables, what you probably could do is the following:

1. Create new Word template
2. Define custom table style with the border for a cell where you are going to place your image
3. Use the template in your Python script with `docx` like this: `document = Document('template.docx')`
4. Apply table style you've just created

Please, read [this thread](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/9) for more details.

Another approach could be less elegant, but 100% working. You just create a border around an image before you use it in `docx`.
You can use `PIL` (for python2) or `Pillow` (for pyhton3) module for the image manipulation.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
img = Image.open('img.png')
img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(img, border=1, fill='black')
img_with_border.save('img-with-border.png')
```

This code will take your `img.png` file and create a new `img-with-border.png` outlined with a 1px black border. Just use `img-with-border.png` in you `run.add_picture` statement then.

Comment: Thank you for the neat `Pillow` idea. This really fixes the problem for the picture - but not for the texts. I will dig into the possibility to template styles for table cells.

Comment: @Stefan if you are fine with the predifined table styles, then just apply one from [this list](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html#table-styles-in-default-template). But if you need a custom style (like makeing a border for a specific single cell), then you have no choice but to create your own template, as I described in my answer.

Comment: Ran into this while looking for ways to leverage quick styles for pictures. Didn't even consider Pillow until reading this post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by vrs in comments, the simplest solution is :

```
table = document.add_table(rows=5, cols=2, style="Table Grid")
```

and add picture to the "run".