# Python-docx: how to add a picture border?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I have an image in document's paragraph:

```
    document.add_picture("image.png")
    last_paragraph = document.paragraphs[-1]
    last_paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

How can i add a 1px border to this picture with python-docx lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's `PIL` library for all image editing tasks. To add a border,

```
def add_border(input_image, output_image, border):
    img = Image.open(input_image)
    if isinstance(border, int) or isinstance(border, tuple):
        bimg = ImageOps.expand(img, border=border)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Border is not an image or tuple')
    bimg.save(output_image)
```

You can now call the function as needed

```
    in_img = 'Demo_Image.png'
    add_border(in_img, output_image='DemoBorder.png', border=1)
```

This will save the output image in your working directory in png format(jpg, if saved as DemoBorder.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, it works. Also i needed to change dpi with `bimg.save(output_image, dpi=(96, 96))` (by default PIL exports to 300*300). If i understand correctly, python-docx doesn't provide image borders?

Comment: As of my knowledge, Python-docx doesn't provide such feature. I've found a related thread on SO. If you wish, you can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555705/frame-around-inline-images